# Docker for Mac Container to Host Networking - Consul Health Checks Connection Refused

Tags: docker, microservices, consul, health-monitoring

I have a HTTP health check in my service, exposed on `localhost:35000/health`. At the moment it always returns `200 OK`. The configuration for the health check is done programmatically via the HTTP API rather than with a service config, but in essence, it is:

```
set id: service-id
set name: health check
set notes: consul does a GET to '/health' every 30 seconds
set http: http://127.0.0.1:35000/health
set interval: 30s
```

When I run consul in dev mode (`consul agent -dev -ui`) on my host machine directly the health check passes without any problem. However, when I run consul in a docker container, the health check fails with:

```
2017/07/08 09:33:28 [WARN] agent: http request failed 'http://127.0.0.1:35000/health': Get http://127.0.0.1:35000/health: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:35000: getsockopt: connection refused
```

The docker container launches consul, as far as I am aware, in exaclty the same state as the host version:

```
version: '2'
services:
  consul-dev:
    image: "consul:latest"
    container_name: "net-sci_discovery-service_consul-dev"
    hostname: "consul-dev"
    ports:
      - "8400:8400"
      - "8500:8500"
      - "8600:8600"
    volumes:
      - ./etc/consul.d:/etc/consul.d
    command: "agent -dev -ui -client=0.0.0.0 -config-dir=/etc/consul.d"
```

I'm guessing the problem is that consul is trying to do the GET request to the containers loopback interface rather than what I am intending, which is for the loopback interface of the host. Is that a correct assumption? More importantly, what do I need to do to correct the problem?

Answer (score 0):

So it transpires that there was a bug in some previous versions of macOS that prevented use of the `docker0` network. Whilst the bug is fixed in newer versions, Docker support extends to older versions and so Docker for Mac doesn't currently support `docker0`. See [this discussion](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/22753) for details.

The workaround is to create an alias to the loopback interface on the host machine, set the service to listen on either that alias or `0.0.0.0`, and configure Consul to send the health check GET request to the alias.

To set the alias (choose a private IP address that's not being used for anything else; I chose a class A address but that's irrelevant):

```
sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 10.200.10.1/24
```

To remove the alias:

```
sudo ifconfig lo0 -alias 10.200.10.1
```

From the service definition above, the HTTP line should now read:

```
set http: http://10.200.10.1:35000/health
```

And the HTTP server listening for the health check requests also needs to be listening on either `10.200.10.2` or `0.0.0.0`. This latter option is suggested in the discussion but I've only tried it with the alias.

I've updated the title of the question to more accurately reflect the problem, now I know the solution. Hope it helps somebody else too.